# AttributeError when using callback Tensorboard on Keras: 'Model' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I have built a model using the functional API from Keras, and when I am adding the tensorboard instance to my callbacks in my model.fit() function,  it throws an Error: `"AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'"`

The Model class does indeed not have an attribute run_eagerly, but in the Keras doc, it says that it can be passed as parameter to the model.compile() function. This returns

```
"ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['run_eagerly']))"
```

Does this mean I don't have a suitable version of Tensorflow/Keras?

> Tensorflow: 1.14.0
>
> Keras: 2.2.4-tf

```
model = Model(inputs=[input_ant1, input_ant2], outputs=main_output)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='.logs/'.format(time()))

[...]

model.fit([input1, input2],[labels], epochs=10, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: Similar issue here.

Comment: same issue. Is this not supported in Keras 2.2.4 with TF 1.x as backend?

Answer (score 11):

I got the same error : `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'`

After two minor changes my tensorboard is running now.

1. make sure you import tensorboard as follows: 
   `from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`
2. change the log dir like this: 
   `tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs")`

Answer (score 1):

I got same error message when I use: 
`from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint`
I fix it with by importing the same as:
`from keras.callbacks.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint`