# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, python-3.7, tensorboard

I'm trying to try using this model to train on rock, paper, scissor pictures. However, it was trained on 1800 pictures and only has an accuracy of 30-40%. I was then trying to use TensorBoard to see whats going on, but the error in the title appears.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(4, 4),
            activation='relu',
            input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(196, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(196, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(196, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(96, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(96, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

''' here it instantiates the tensorboard '''
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="C:/Users/bamla/Desktop/RPS project/Logs")

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer="SGD",
        metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

''' Here its fitting the model '''
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs = 3, callbacks= 
[tensorboard])
```

This outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:/Users/bamla/Desktop/RPS project/Testing.py", line 82, in <module>
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs = 3, callbacks= 
[tensorboard])

File "C:\Users\bamla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1178, in fit
validation_freq=validation_freq)

File "C:\Users\bamla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 125, in fit_loop
callbacks.set_model(callback_model)

 File "C:\Users\bamla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 68, in set_model
callback.set_model(model)

File "C:\Users\bamla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1509, in set_model
if not model.run_eagerly:

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'
```

Also, if you have any tips on how to improve the accuracy it would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220347/attributeerror-when-using-callback-tensorboard-on-keras-model-object-has-no-a ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

Do not mix `keras` and `tf.keras` imports, these are **not compatible with each other**, and produce weird errors as the ones you are seeing.

Comment: so should i use keras or tf.keras in this use case?

Comment: @BT That is up to you.

Comment: Use `from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard` from https://keras.io/callbacks/

Answer (score 2):

I changed `from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`
 to `from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this did the job:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow import keras
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mixing imports from `keras` and `tensorflow.keras` (last one is preferred).

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/

> And most importantly, going forward all deep learning practitioners
>   should switch their code to TensorFlow 2.0 and the tf.keras package.
>   The original keras package will still receive bug fixes, but moving
>   forward, you should be using tf.keras.

Try with:

```
import tensorflow
Conv2D = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D
MaxPooling2D = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D
Dense = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense
Flatten = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten
Dropout = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout
TensorBoard = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
```